# Vue.js proxy/target doesnt work when in a different route then the "{baseurl}/" route

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, proxy

So i have a vue project where i have a js file that requests data from an API and that goes fine. I set up a proxy in my vue.config.js file so that every request starting with /api will be redirected to the baseurl of the API, like this:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://dev.liveflow.nl'
      },
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine for when im in my websites base url and do an axios.get request like `axios.get(api/batches/)`. But when im in my websites 'batches' route, and i do `axios.get(api/batches/:id/`, the proxy doesnt work. Instead of requesting to (target from the vue.config.js file above) `target/api/batches/:id`, its requesting to my own websites `url/batches/api/batches/:id`. So the problem is, that because im in the /batches route, it will leave the /batches in the url, so the proxy i configured doesnt work (i think)

So the code i use in my js file to do all http requests looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "api/batches/";

class BatchService {
    // Get Batches
    static async getBatches() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(url);
            const data = res.data;

            return data;
        } catch(err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

    // Get Batch by ID
    static async getBatchById(id) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${url}${id}`);
            const data = res.data;

            return data;
        } catch(err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

export default BatchService;
```

Because of the proxy, i only have to do "api/batches/" as url, because the proxy recognizes the /api and redirects it to the target.

These to methods work fine when im in my websites baseurl, but when im in a different route, like baseurl/batches, the requests does baseurl/batches/api/batches/:id, while i want it to be target/api/batches/:id.

The error i get is simple: GET http://localhost:8080/batches/api/batches/63722a8ab1194203d268b220 404 (Not Found). It is just requesting the wrong url and using the websites baseurl instead of the target baseurl.

BTW: I need to do the proxy setup. When i just do const url = "target/api/batches/" the API server will deny my request

My english is not that good so i hope im clear enough.

Comment: Don't use relative urls with no leading slash without a good reason. Axios has base url option. It's supposed to help here.

Comment: @EstusFlask but when i use the baseurl option from axios, i dont need to proxy/target setup anymore right? Because the baseurl will make sure it uses the api website instead of my own website right?

Comment: They aren't interchangeable. A proxy is needed for CORS, cookies and other documented features. If you're sure you don't need them and can go with base url alone then yes, you don't need a proxy.

Comment: I meant `/` base url actually, it will work with the proxy. Or do all requests with leading slash